# Instagram API Not Loading All Images

Tags: javascript, api, for-loop, instagram

I'm attempting to use the Instagram API to pull all images tagged with the specific tag "watchsuburbia"

It's working, put not fully, it only pulls 18 photos, last night it was only pulling 17...no matter how I set up my loop. There are currently almost 40 photos it should be pulling (currently the loop is set to only 25).

You can see what I'm attempting at http://himynameismarvin.com/instahelp

Here is the function (I removed my API info for this post but have it included and working in my version):

```
$(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"jsonp",
            cache:false,
            url:"https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/watchsuburbia/media/recent?client_id=[CLIENTID]&access_token=[ACCESSTOKEN]",
            success:function(data){
                for(var i=0; i<25; i++){
                    $("#pics").append("<div class='instaframe'><a target='_blank' href='"+data.data[i].link+"'><img src='"+data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url+"' /></a></div>");
                }
            }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [doc](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) says that you can pass a `count` parameter:

> On views where pagination is present, we also support the "count"
>   parameter. Simply set this to the number of items you'd like to
>   receive. Note that the default values should be fine for most
>   applications - but if you decide to increase this number there is a
>   maximum value defined on each endpoint.

I didn't see it in your test page so I tried it. I can get consistently 32 elements, but no more. I guess that's a limit on Instagram's side.

Comment: Yes! This works. I actually fixed it early but wasn't allowed to self-answer for 7 hours! I was able to set it to something like 200 and it would work for all the photos. I also now put in some pagination and everything is wonderful, thank you!

Comment: @himynameismarvin , for the pagination, how did you tell instagram you want the NEXT 200 and not the same 200?  I've been looking at this max_id and min_id stuff and it doesn't seem to be working out.

Comment: I seem to have figured this out 20 minutes later, it was a bit confusing. You only need to pass the instagram api the "max_tag_id". In case anyone else runs into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Instafetch**](https://github.com/d4nyll/instafetch/)!

The Instagram API imposes a silent, undocumented limit on how many results it returns. Even if you pass in a `count` higher than `33`, it will only return, at most, 33 results.

Instafetch eliminates this limit at the cost of making more API calls. At the moment, it works if you query by user, and you can filter by tag after too.

<sub>Disclaimer: Written by me</sub>